# How to say "May I take the quiz" in French?

Tags: grammaire, usage, temps-grammatical, participe-passé

After school, I plan on taking a quiz I missed in French class from last Friday. My teacher requires my class to almost always speak in French, so I intend on asking if I may take the test after school.

I would like to show respect using:

> Puis-je (May I)...

I am asking my teacher if I can take the quiz in the future. Would this require future tense, such as:

> Après l'école, puis-je passerai l'interro de vendredi?

Or,

> Après l'école, puis-je passer l'interro de vendredi?

Comment: I don't think it would be necessary to further clarify that your request is for something in the future by using the future tense, but if you want to do it anyway, I think you would put "pouvoir" in the future tense (in fact, I'd use the conditional) and not "passer" (which should remain in the infinitive, imo): "Pourrai[s]-je [re]passer/[Est-ce que je pourrais repasser] l'interro de vendredi/du vendredi passé?"

Comment: In English, you wouldn't use the future so why would you in French? May I take the quiz  is present.

Answer (score 3):

Although it may sound quite illogical since the quiz was never taken in the first place, most French students would say:

"Est-ce que je peux **re**faire ou repasser l'interro de vendredi après les cours?"

de is also better than du, unless you take a quiz every Friday.

nota: people tend to say "évaluation" ou "éval'" nowadays;; "l'interro" is slightly outdated.

Comment: Why would  you say refaire ou repasser if you never took it??

Comment: Because that's what French people would say. I'm not saying it's logical but that is what you hear (and I'm a teacher in France so I hear a lot of that stuff) Est-ce que je pourrais rattraper l'éval'? is also something you could hear. In fact, yes, that's much better than the previous sentences, now that I think of it:  rattraper.

Answer (score 2):

The good answer is "Pourrai-je passer l'interro **de** vendredi ?".
"Puis-je passerai l'interro du vendredi ?" is not good. 
Basically, you should conjugate only one verb by sentence member.
In your sentence, there is only one sentence member
so you can only conjugate "pouvoir" and "passer" must stay at the infinitive.

Comment: I have mistaken past tense for future tense. I say this in the updated post, but would "Puis-je passerai l'interro du vendredi?" be correct?

Comment: @Distic Vous avez  mis la même phrase deux fois en français?

Comment: *Puis-je passerai is not correct. Pourrai-je passer...would do the trick I suppose

Comment: Oh, sorry: passé and passer. My apologies. Actually, the mistake would be: May I took the quiz. :)

Comment: @Lambie: No it is "taken". Took would be "passais".

Comment: @Bibliophile: user45784 is correct.

Comment: @Distic OK, you have changed your answer, and I don't remember exactly what  you had originally in French. Je  **passais** l'examen, **was taking**, **used to take**, or even **took** (depending on the context).  It would never be taken, sorry. And since you corrected my French, allow me to correct  your English: la bonne réponse is the correct answer, not good answer. Sentence member is not something we say. And finally, we say: stay **in** the infinitive. Now, do you think my editing helps your answer?

Comment: @Lambie : Thanks for the corrections. Feel free to edit. "taken" (or taking if you prefer) can be used without being the verb of the sentence, like "passé" but unlike "took" (up to my knowledge). Anyway, it makes no sense to translate mistakes...